# How to update global object value?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure about best practice that how to deal with it:

```
const obj = {a: null}
function getObject(){
  // I may return a, or anything that could be nested property
  return obj.a
}
let v = getObject()
v = 'updated'
console.log(obj.a) // null
```

I expect `a` value co-operates with v assignment. I have seen with operator but people say avoid using it. So, what should I be using?

Comment: When I console obj.a, it should return that I assigned with v.

Comment: getObject doesn't return a reference to the field 'a', though it can return a reference to an object stored in 'a'. What you're trying won't work. You'd need to return obj, and set the field on it directly.

Comment: I want to update a from reference of v but i know it's not a reference.

Comment: Then do `obj.a = "updated"`? If you print `v` after the `let v = getObject()` line, you'll see it's `null`, so the idea that reassigning it to a string would mutate `obj.a` is wrong. Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please offer context for what you're really trying to achieve here.

Comment: To assign a value to a property of an Object (`obj`), you need a reference to this object (`obj`). As soon as you did `v = obj.a`, `v` has no reference to `obj`. You can still update `a` if it's an Array or an Object. But you cannot assign a new value

Comment: That's why I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: obj.a = v ?    is this working?

Comment: That would be harder way I think. There could be any number of deep object. And from the getObject function I will be returning to desired property and now I want to get updated value.

Comment: sorry, but it makes no sense and should be clear that you are simply setting new values.

Comment: Yes. I want to set new value but after getting them. The get function may return any property I wish.

Comment: But your are clearing overriding the value - if you cannot see this, then please cover the basics of variables before posting. Some links [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function returns the value of a field/variable then you get a reference to the object stored in that field/variable, not a reference to the variable itself. You either need to have getObject() return an object, which you then set the field value on, like so:

```
function getObject(){
 return obj;
}

getObject().a = 'something';
```

Or you need to write a function that assigns the field value instead, like so:

```
function setValue(val) {
   obj.a = val;
}
```

Another option would be to wrap your values in objects, so getObject never returns null, instead returning an empty object on which you set a field value, like so:

```
const obj = {a: {}}

function getObject(){
  return obj.a
}

let v = getObject();

v.value = "foo";
// obj now equals {a: {value: "foo"}}
```

As written you're returning the value currently stored in a, saving that to a variable, then changing the value in the new variable. The value in obj remains unchanged.

Comment: It would be harder way I think. How can I deal with nested properties that I want to update?

Comment: You could always have your setter method take a path, or an array of field names.

Comment: I've added one more alternative for if you're really attached to returning a reference you then modify.

Comment: Seems to be a solution for me. I'll wait if there's any other option without this trick.

Comment: You may find some other approach that you like more, but there's no way to return a reference to a field in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any Javascript object using dot like what you had in getObject , also you can set value to the object like this `anyObject.key = value` this will change the value of the key in the object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = new Object({ a : null })
Object.prototype.setA = function(a) {
  this.a = a
}
obj.setA('hello world!')
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a global object values you need to access the object and assign it

```
const obj = {a: null}
function getObject(){
  return obj.a
}
let v = getObject()


console.log(getObject()) //null
console.log(obj.a) // null

obj.a = "a" //you are now overriding what was null here
console.log(obj.a) //contains "a" now or whatever type you want it to be
```

I'd recommend you check this helpful tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

you are changing the value of `v` and not changing the object referenced by `v`

Long answer:

**If this was written in a class-based langauge (like C, java, or C++, etc.), this would also not change `a`. Because you are only changing what `v` points or reference to (in case of pointers).**

In C :

```
void *v = (void*) &getObject() // v is equal to obj (or points to obj) obj
v = (void*) &some.thing.something() // v is now equal to some.thing.something() or points to some.thing.something()

// obj has not changed

print(obj.a) // null which is reasonable

// printf ("%s", obj.a); is the correct syntax in C
```

To actually change `a` you need to change the value of of the address in memory that is referenced by `v`

In C:

```
void *v = (void*) &getObject()
*v = (void *) some.thing.something()
print(obj.a) // now obj is equal to 'some.thing.something()'

// printf ("%s", obj.a); is the correct syntax in C
```

**Now in your code why `a` is not changing ?**

When it comes to Javascript, it is a langauge based on prototypes, rather than class-based

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

Check the link above.

It is because of the same reason explained in the first `C` code above. You are just changing the value of `v` and not changing the object referenced by `v`

```
let v = getObject()
v = 'some.thing.something()'
console.log(obj.a) // null
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding JS variables is important:

```
let a = 1;
console.log(a); //1
a = 2;//overrides a
console.log(a); //2
```

What you are trying to achieve is not very clear but I would recommend to always mutate the global var to avoid errors and confusion.